# To change text using regular expressions, if we cannot use replace() but have to use matchAll(), how is it done?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following is a tricky regex question. Let's see if we can try to reach a general rule of solving this type of questions by regex approaches:

Let's say if we have a badly formatted string:

```
2020-01-02 go supermarket 2020-01-03 wash dish\ndo laundry 2020-01-04
wash car 2020-01-05 clean up
```

The requirement is to break the dates out on their separate lines, with some newlines before and after.  It is optional to add a horizontal line after the date to make it look nicer.

There can be some text before the appearance of the first date, so that text should be in the result as well.  (just saying that it can be any text and dates intermixed together, and the result should contain all original text).

Maybe because I have been doing a lot of array problems recently, so the first attempt was to use `match()` or `matchAll()` to do it.  But it was a bit tricky, and the last part was missing in the result (see below: the text `"clean up"` is not showing).  And I thought of using `split()` and `join()`... and it turned out that `replace()` should be just the same and cleaner, and seemed like perfectly fitted to do the job:

```js
const s = '2020-01-02 go supermarket 2020-01-03 wash dish\ndo laundry 2020-01-04 wash car 2020-01-05 clean up';

let result = s.replace(/((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(\s*))/g, '\n\n$2  ----------------------\n\n');

result = result.replace(/^\n*/, '');  // <-- hacky
console.log(result);
```

But even the need to remove the extra `\n` at the beginning was a bit hacky -- is there a better way if we use this `replace()` approach?

#### And the main question really is: if the requirement is that we cannot use `replace()` or `split()` or `join()`, but only use `match()` or `matchAll()`, how can it be done?

The following has the problem of (1) extra newlines at the beginning of the result and (2) the last item after the date is missing (The text `"clean up"` is not showing). It seems messy because we can't use greedy matching, and then the last part of original text won't get matched, because there is no date at the very end any more:

```js
const s = '2020-01-02 go supermarket 2020-01-03 wash dish\ndo laundry 2020-01-04 wash car 2020-01-05 clean up';

let result = '';
let matches = s.matchAll(/([^]*?)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\s*))([^]*?)/g);

for (let m of matches) {
  result += m[1] + '\n\n' + m[2] + '  --------------------\n\n' + m[4];
}

console.log(result);
```

Is it true that basically, we can use (1) `match()`, `matchAll()`, or (2) `replace()`, `split()`, `join()` to solve this kind of problems? That is, if `match()` and `matchAll()` doesn't seem to work well, we really should immediately consider the second way of using `replace()`? (I think `split()` and `join()` are just the same as `replace()`).  I hope to get a general rule that, if the `matchAll()` doesn't seem to solve the problem well, then we should really consider the second type of method for this kind of problem, which is to use `replace()`.

One reason I hope to have such a general rule is because (1) for my own knowledge as a bag of tricks to solve such problems, and (2) in a phone or onsite interview, if I get stuck using the `matchAll()` method for 10 minutes and still try to solve it using `matchAll()`, I might get shallow judged that I am not a good programmer and get turned down for that.

Comment: I ran your code snippet, which uses `s.matchAll()`, and the output looks like it's correct.  Is there something not right with this?  "2020-01-02   -------------------- go supermarket", etc.?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger the last part is missing. The text "clean up" is missing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) was a good choice here for swapping over from `replace()`.  I decided to clean up your regex just a little bit, so that it would be easier to understand.  Full working demo at [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pitaqovodi/edit?html,js,console).

I changed this part...

```
var regex = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})([0-9a-zA-Z\s\n\r]+)(\s|$)/g
let matches = s.matchAll(regex);
```

And your forloop:

```
for (let m of matches) {
  result += m[1] + '  --------------------\n\n' + m[2] + '\n\n';
}
```

Now the regex is directly matching the date pattern followed by some text.

- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` : Match the date.
- `([0-9a-zA-Z\s\n\r]+)` : Match the things to do on the date.
- `(\s|$)` : Match the end of the string or the beginning of the next item.

Naturally, with regular expressions, there can *always be problems*.  What if you have a note that says "Don't forget to do this on 2020-01-02"?  But that is a general regex problem.  The better you normalize your data in general, the easier you'll be able to adapt and change your code.

To make things a bit tricky, I added "1456" to one of your todo items, because another solution that looks at `\d{4}` incorrectly might mess up the regex matching here, and incorrectly indicate it to be a new item or a date.

Output:

```
2020-01-02  --------------------
 go supermarket1456
2020-01-03  --------------------
 wash dish
do laundry
2020-01-04  --------------------
 wash car
2020-01-05  --------------------
 clean up
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work if the string has `"what to do "` added to the very beginning. "There can be some text before the appearance of the first date, so that text should be in the result as well"

Comment: @nonopolarity: Ah, and this is why regexes are not preferable to normalized data! =)  Try changing the regex by adding `([^\d]*)`?  So we have: `var regex = /([^\d]*)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})([0-9a-zA-Z\s\n\r]+)(\s|$)/g`?  And change the match indices?  `result += m[1] + m[2]`?  Seems to work: https://jsbin.com/tagujegesa/edit?html,js,console (I can update answer if it's good)

Comment: I think it doesn't work... it will make the first line `begin list! 2020-01-02  ----------------` but all the other dates have newlines before and after.  You can add the snippet right on Stock Overflow by clicking on that snippet icon

Comment: @nonopolarity: I'm still not sure what's wrong.  The link in the comment is displaying some text "before the appearance of the first date," and I arbitrarily set that text to "begin list!".  What's wrong exactly?

Comment: don't you see in your jsbin snippet?  The first date doesn't have newlines before it

Comment: @nonopolarity: I thought the problem is trivial?  This is how you add newlines to a string in JS: `if(m[1]) { result += m[1] + '\n\n';}` https://jsbin.com/wubitigewo/1/edit?html,js,console  Is the problem strictly that there's a newline here or there that you didn't want?  You can change that in the foreach very easily.  Or is it something else?

Comment: the requirement to begin with is to add newlines before and after the dates, so it is not satisfying the initial (and main) requirement we started out with

Comment: @nonopolarity Some basic string manipulation, no problem? 
 https://jsbin.com/cetecohifu/edit?html,js,console

Comment: If the test string begins with `123 lets go 2020-01-02 go supermarket` it doesn't work... it is this type of situation in interviews that it is going for 20 minutes and it still doesn't work and you kind of feel that it is a "no hire"... perhaps this question is tough if using matchAll() and that's why the other angle of replace() makes it quite a lot simpler

Comment: @nonopolarity: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by "no hire"? And "20 minutes"? 
 Am I on the clock?  We just spent some time because it seems like your first question here is that you didn't know how to concat strings?  Anyway, here's the same string-concat technique, once again: https://jsbin.com/ruxafuzara/1/edit?js,console

Comment: No, I mean no hire feeling if I got into such situation. Regex can be tricky, as the saying goes, you got one problem and you see it can be solved by regex, and now you have 2 problems

Answer (score 1):

To deal with possible text before the first date, you can use a regex which looks for some text before a date (`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`) and then other characters up to either the next date or end of string (`$`). When processing the matches, if the first capture group is defined we output it, otherwise we just output the date and its corresponding actions:

```js
const s = 'some random text 2020-01-02 go supermarket 2020-01-03 wash dish\ndo laundry, if have time 2020-01-04 wash car 2020-01-05 clean up';

let matches = s.matchAll(/([^]*?)?\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s*([^]*?)(?=\s*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$)/g);

let result = '';
for (const match of matches) {
  if (match[1] !== undefined) {
    result += match[1] + '\n\n';
  }
  result += match[2] + '  --------------------\n\n' + match[3] + '\n'
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: "And the main question really is: if the requirement is that we cannot use replace() or split() or join(), but only use match() or matchAll(), how can it be done?"

Comment: For some reason I am blind to bold text... :-)

Comment: @nonopolarity I've updated my answer to use `matchAll`.

Comment: basically working... except if the input starts with a date, there is an extra newline at the beginning of output...  if the input is changed from "do laundry" to "do laundry, if have time", then it would break too...

Comment: @nonopolarity see my edit. I think that resolves those issues.

Comment: seems to work well... interesting... you are using non-greedy to match the extra text after the date but then you use a look ahead to make sure it reaches before another date or end of string...

Comment: @nonopolarity exactly, since the `[^]*` will match anything, it needs to be told where to stop, in this case at the next date (or end of string).